# Fast forward merge failing in git

Tags: git, merge

I will preface this by saying that I am pretty new to git. However, this seems like a pretty straightforward scenario, and I can't see where the problem is coming from. Here is the scenario:

I am on the master branch with some uncommitted changes that I don't want. I need to make a separate simple change to be packaged into a patch.  So I do this:

I find the hash # for the last commit to the master branch which is  ffdd99afc89211e9ddc3efa3415b0adaf0076b4b.

So from the root of my repository I do:

```
git branch my_patch ffdd99afc89211e9ddc3efa3415b0adaf0076b4b
git checkout -f my_patch
```

Now I edit three files and add a fourth after which I do:

```
git add [path to the added file]
git status
```

this lists the three updated and one added file

```
git commit -a
git status
```

no changes found

```
git format-patch master --stdout > my_patch.patch
```

All is good to this point. Now I want to merge this branch back into master.

```
git checkout master
git status
```

No changes found

```
git merge my_patch
```

The output from which is:

```
Updating ffdd99a..e2754ca 
error: Your local changes to 'Blah.cs' would be overwritten by merge. 
Aborting. Please, commit your changes
or stash them before you can merge.
```

And now if I do `git status` I get a boat load of changes listed.  Does this make any sense to anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want the changes when you start, do a `git reset --hard`. And if there are untracked files there that you don't want do a `git clean -df` as well.

As for your error message at the end, you may have an issue with casing in the path. Is this on Windows w/ msysgit?

If you are on windows, ensure you have autocrlf set to false.

Comment: Okay so this is even weirder. Starting where i left off above, with git status showing a bunch of modified files (as in about 120), I do a git reset --hard.  I get the response, HEAD is now at ffdd99a Fixed failing... (Fixed failing.... being the message associated with ffdd99a).  git status STILL shows the same 120 mods. So I tried git clean -df which removed a trio of empty directories only.  Thereafter, git status again shows the same 120 mods.  I can do git checkout my_patch and this fails, listing 1 file local changes.  Adding -f works.

Comment: Picking up from the last comment where git checkout -f my_patch got me to my_patch: after this git status says I am clean,  nothing to commit, no added files.  So I git checkout master and I am back to the 120 modified files that I can't make go away.  Moreover doing a git diff on any of the files, shows all lines being deleted and then re-added with no effective change?!

Comment: sounds like you have line ending issues.

Comment: I added that to the end of my answer.

Comment: Setting autoclrf to false was the solution to the problem.

Comment: it got me the first time too :)